# Test mobile website compatibility

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, cross-browser, mobile-browser

I am developing a mobile website using JQuery mobile, HTML 5. I want to test my site in various browsers. Can some one tell me some of the **mobile browsers** to test on ? I want to check whether it works fine on all touch enabled phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a poll on lifehacker:

- Firefox  10.4%  (1,338 votes)
- Chrome  38.35%  (4,935 votes)
- Dolphin HD/Mini  25.29%  (3,254 votes)
- Boat Browser/Mini  2.2%  (283 votes)
- Opera Mobile/Mini  23.76%  (3,057 votes)

For iPhone:

are the same as above plus : Atomic, Mercury, Photon, Switch, Webout, CloudBrowse

In my opinion if you want to be sure you have to test it on different devices, with different screen resolutions, not just on different browsers.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested my mobile site in all the above mentioned browsers and it works great except in Opera mini. Its looks as if its a desktop site in IE 6. Any solutions ?

Comment: I think @smoothButter below mentioned some very good tools about testing. Check them ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the various screen sizes and not different browsers specifically, you can use something like these two, both of which offer emulation for a variety of smartphones and tablets.

```
https://quirktools.com/screenfly/
http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/
```

If you need to specifically test functionality in the browsers themselves (real browsers, not just the screen size adjustment) check out http://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator, or you can download and run the actual emulators themselves and check thing out that way. I'd say the most popular browsers include the default Android browser, Safari, Chrome, Mozilla, Dolphin, and Opera (all mobile versions of course).